# Careers 2.0 bug -> safari window resizing cuts off text & images

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I don't speak web dev so I'll try to describe in plain english as best I can.

Running Careers 2.0 in Safari vs 5.0.4

When the horizontal window size is smaller than the minimum page width a horizontal scroll bar appears in Safari.  When I scroll to the right, the part of the page not originally visible is not viewable, everything to the right of the originally viewable area is blank.  When the Safari window is re-sized so that horizontal scroll bar is no longer present, the full page is viewable again.

This bug does not appear present in the other Stack-Overflow pages, just Careers 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed now.  Thanks for the report.

This was also happening in Chrome, for what it's worth.